# How to create a new variable that resets based on a condition in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe in r:

|  | block | time | xp | yp | ps | cr.info | ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2150472 | 1021. | 565. | 3485 | ... | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2150473 | 1021. | 565. | 3481 | ... | 0.001 |
| 3 | 1 | 2150474 | 1021. | 565. | 3477 | ... | 0.002 |
| 4 | 1 | 2150475 | 1021. | 564 | 3478 | ... | 0.003 |

The variable "ts" increases in milliseconds for entire dataset, I would like to create a new variable which also increases in milliseconds but which starts from zero each time the conditional variable  "block" changes value, so that each block has its own separate timer, as demonstrated in the table below.

|  | block | time | xp | yp | ps | cr.info | ts | block_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2150472 | 1021. | 565. | 3485 | ... | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2150473 | 1021. | 565. | 3481 | ... | 0.001 | 0.001 |
| 3 | 1 | 2150474 | 1021. | 565. | 3477 | ... | 0.002 | 0.002 |
| 4 | 1 | 2150475 | 1021. | 564 | 3478 | ... | 0.003 | 0.003 |
| 5 | 2 | 2150476 | 1040. | 578. | 5678 | ... | 0.004 | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | 2150477 | 1041. | 579. | 5688 | ... | 0.005 | 0.001 |

Thanks in advance,

Sean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a group by operation.  After grouping by 'block', create the `seq`uence from `0`, specify the `length.out` as the number of rows for each block (`n()`) and the `by` as the increment in each step

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(block) %>%
    mutate(block_ts = seq(0, length.out = n(), by = 0.001))
```